# What is the Maximum number of files that can be upload

Tags: php

I can see `max_file_uploads=100` at my phpinfo.

I want to upload near about 100 files together.But I see it does not post more that 25 file inputs.
For test I made following script

```
<form action="filecheck.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php
            for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
            {

                if(($i%5)==0)
                {
                    echo '<br>';
                }
                echo $i." ";
                ?>
                <input type="file" name="file_<?=$i?>">
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
```

my filechceck.php is like this

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
```

I just select first and 100th file and clicked save.

At my localhost the output is OK which is like this

```
Array
(
    [file_1] => Array
        (
            [name] => a.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => *****\php8019.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 203
        )

    [file_2] => Array
        (
            [name] =>
            [type] =>
            [tmp_name] =>
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )
        ....
    [file_99] => Array
        (
            [name] =>
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )
        [file_100] => Array
        (
            [name] => b.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => ****\php801A.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 203
        )

)
```

But at my live server it shows like this

```
Array
(
    [file_1] => Array
        (
            [name] => a.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phplbJzsi
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 203
        )

    [file_2] => Array
        (
            [name] =>
            [type] =>
            [tmp_name] =>
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )
    ....
    [file_24] => Array
        (
            [name] =>
            [type] =>
            [tmp_name] =>
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [file_25] => Array
        (
            [name] =>
            [type] =>
            [tmp_name] =>
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Is there anything else I need to set at my php.ini? to work it perfectly as my localserver?

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the size?

Comment: There are two places it would be limited. In your php ini, and your server config. There's a max post upload size you will probably need to alter. And then restart the server.

Comment: I did restarted. That's why my phpinfo shows `max_file_uploads=100`.

Comment: Are there two  different `php.ini` files for `development` and `production`? Because, on my local machine, there are two of them.

Comment: @PrerakSola only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running suhosin which limits it to 25:

> suhosin.upload.max_uploads    25  25

<sub><sub>Op shared his `phpinfo()` output with me</sub></sub>